# ldap.conf simple auth

Tags: configuration, openldap

I am trying to configure ldap.conf for openldap. I am trying to do simple authentication like you can do with the `-x` in the ldapsearch commad. We currently have a script that uses a complex ldapsearch command and we want to default many of the configuration settings in the ldap.conf file. We can't seem to find an alternative to `-x`.

Our config is currently set for `URI` and `BASE` which when we do an ldapsearch with the `-x` option works correctly. However we want any client applications that use the ldap.conf config file to use simple authentication and so we cannot rely on the `-x` all the time. Is there a way to specify this in ldap.conf file?

Currently when we run the command without the `-x` we get the following error:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Unknown authentication method (-6)
    additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found
```

thanks,

Comment: Did you test out the SASL options in `ldap.conf`, especially `SASL_SECPROPS none`?

Comment: It doesnt not look like the script uses SASL options so I have not included any in the config file

Answer (score 1):

What got the desired behavior for me:

```
$ grep SASL_ /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
SASL_MECH      ANONYMOUS
SASL_SECPROPS  none
```

Comment: SASL/ANONYMOUS authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Authentication method not supported (7)
        additional info: SASL not supported

Comment: Worked for me with ds-389 server, but not with openldap…